# speculating on applicant's national origin and gender

Tags: resume, applications

I have noticed colleagues, when reviewing applicant resumes together, sometimes speculate on the national origin and gender of the applicant (usually based on their name).  This seems to be harmless curiosity and does not seem to be affecting hiring decisions, but I'm wondering if this is inappropriate enough to mention something.  Is it?

Comment: Who are you wanting to mention it too and for what purpose?

Comment: @user1084 You can't know that it is affecting hiring decisions. That's an assumption you're making based on your own prejudices.

Answer (score 8):

Legally? Don't know, but off the record and probably <del>fine</del> at risk per JeffO's answer.

Ethically? Definitely inappropriate. You have it backwards. *Discrimination is automatic and requires conscious correction*. So when you say:

> does not seem to be affecting hiring decisions

my reaction is, "When did they do something specific to make you think that?" Fortunately this is a good learning opportunity. Bringing the subject up (assuming you have the tact and/or sway to do so, tread carefully) is a good way to say, "I know this looks trivial, but we need to be *extremely* diligent in the hiring process." Feel free to point to [numerous](http://www.nber.org/digest/sep03/w9873.html) [studies](http://abcnews.go.com/blogs/business/2013/07/man-named-kim-adds-mr-to-resume-lands-job/) and anecdotes on the topic.

This ['How to Fight Race and Gender Bias in Science' Editorial in the Oct 2014 issue of Scientic American](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/how-to-fight-race-and-gender-bias-in-science-editorial/) sums ups the issue quite nicely.

Comment: OK I see that your answer explains your comment on the question... I think since you gave an answer, it would be clearer to delete your comment on the question.

Answer (score 5):

The North American perspective would be that nationality/ethnicity is completely out of bounds in the hiring process and this would be a very touchy subject.  If this is N America I would strongly recommend bringing it up.  The appearance of bias is just as bad as actual bias.

In many other places (eg S Korea) this would be normal and not a big issue at all.

Comment: Out of curiousity, why do you say this would be normal in places like South Korea, but not North America? Is this a cultural difference, or a legal difference?

Comment: I think both.  When I was in South Korea, a foreigner's nationality was required as a part job applications so there would be no legal expectation of privacy in this respect and it was common to refer to new hires by their nationality until you met them (ie "The new Australian teacher arrives on Tuesday").

Answer (score 2):

It only takes one person who doesn't get hired who happens to have a different ethnicity to turn this into a legal problem. A former or current employee who is aware of these comments could become a whistle-blower if they have a grievance with the company, want to stand up for the person who didn't get hired or they just think it is wrong.

It's all fun and games until someone gets hurt.

Answer (score -1):

In real-world terms, it seems to me that it would depend on what people are doing about it. It might very well be harmless curiosity. If someone sees an unfamiliar name, there's nothing startling about the idea that they might wonder, "Hmm, Vietnhi, is that a boy's name or a girl's name?" My ancestors are from Norway, and I've very often had people ask me if my name is Norwegian, Swedish, or something else. I've never supposed that they wanted to know so that they could decide whether or not to discriminate against me. I always figured it was just idle curiosity or making conversation.

If people at the company are speculating about someone's national origin based on their name, and when the consensus is that the name is French they throw the resume out but every other nationality they keep, then yes, there's a problem.

I suppose that if someone brought a discrimination lawsuit, the fact that people talked about their nationality could be used as evidence in court. Sad that people who have no intent to discriminate have to live in fear that an innocent desire to learn a little about other cultures could be taken wrong, but that's life in modern America, I guess.